# A working combination of Qt and OSX for deploying universal binaries

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, cmake, macdeployqt

Since I ran across many many problems in setting up a build system for building large qt projects and deploying them as universal OSX binaries, I just want to ask if somebody know a flawless combination of operating system (OSX leopard, snow leopard, lion, mountain lion) and Qt version to have a deploy system that just works.

I just want the following things:

1) No compilator issues
2) A **working** macdeployqt command
3) Full compatibility with CMake to build projects.

A combination of these last 3 points seemed to be such a pain in the back for me when I was trying to make a universal dmg with OSX 10.5.8 (leopard with gcc 4.0.1), Qt 4.7.1 and CMake 2.8.7!